# Преобразовать ФИО в Фамилия И.О. (ASCII/Unicode)

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть список ФИО людей на русском языке. Примерно такой:

`full_names = [u"Иванов Иван Иванович", u"Петров Петр Петрович"]`

Моя задача укоротить их ФИО до "Фамилия И.О." в максимально компактном виде.
Я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
full_names = [u"Иванов Иван Иванович", u"Петров Петр Петрович"]
short_names = [' '.join([fn.split(' ')[0],fn.split(' ')[0][1]]) for fn in full_names]
```

Вот так можно получить формат "Фамилия И"

Есть ли более элегантный способ?

Comment: почему одна строка?

Comment: Так задача становится интереснее. Многострочное решение будет выглядеть банально :)

Comment: Если это code golf вопрос, то следуйте правилам для подобных вопросов (посмотрите на [meta]). Если нет, то уберите ограничение на одну строку или объясните чем вызвано такое требование.

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое code golf вопрос. Это нужно для моих личных нужд. Хорошо, пусть будет много строк.

Comment: [Метка для гольф-вопросов](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2958/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: @Skotinin вот что [такое](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84)

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать. Код моего приложения получается итак слишком размашистый, поэтому хотел его сжать визуально немного.

Comment: @Skotinin потом читать и исправлять будет очень трудно, не надо так

Comment: Я пока не пишу настолько крутые коды, что в них будет рыться кто-то другой :) А мне так удобнее кажется. Вся проблема локализована в одной строке. При отладке кода, одну строку очень просто закомментить. Сейчас я пишу дашборд, который показывает всякие рейтинги, длиные ФИО оцениваемых сотрудников не влазят, либо плохо смотрятся на графиках в браузере `Chart.js`. В текущем коде нужно уделить основное внимание расчетам, а не преобразованиям ФИО и прочим мелочам. Поэтому хочу это сделать в одну строку и забыть, чтоб не мешалось.

Comment: А надо писать так, чтобы «сделать это в одну ФУНКЦИЮ и забыть, чтоб не мешалось». Один вызов функции тоже очень легко закомментировать. А ещё эту функцию можно (и нужно) покрыть юнит-тестами :)

Answer (score 6):

Лучше воспользоватся стандартным format:

{:.1} - берет только первый символ

```
['{} {:.1}. {:.1}.'.format(*n.split()) for n in full_names]
```

имя/отчество уже необязательно:

```
def get_full_names(names: list):
    def fio_name(fio: str):
        ifs = iter(fio.split())
        yield next(ifs)
        for name in ifs: yield name[0]+'.'
    return [' '.join(fio_name(n)) for n in names]
```

Comment: Не забывайте тестировать такие функции, например таким ФИО *Ашуршанова Лейла Садар кызы*

Answer (score 4):

Если в одну строчку и если формат строго `u"Фамилия Имя Отчество"` (ровно два пробела), то у меня получилось вот так:

```
short_names = [u'{} {}. {}.'.format(x[:x.find(' ')], x[x.find(' ') + 1], x[x.rfind(' ') + 1]) for x in full_names]
```

Развёрнуто:

```
short_names = [
    u'{} {}. {}.'.format(    # Шаблон, в который подставим строки
        x[:x.find(' ')],     # Всё до первого пробела - Фамилия
        x[x.find(' ') + 1],  # Первая буква после первого пробела - И.
        x[x.rfind(' ') + 1]  # Первая буква после последнего пробела - О.
    )
    for x in full_names
]
```

Но всё-таки для чего-то серьёзного настоятельно рекомендую использовать какой-нибудь понятный развёрнутый многострочный вариант, ибо надёжнее, проще в поддержке и проще расширить под непредвиденные ситуации (например, не у всех людей есть отчество, и такой однострочник сломается).

Comment: `short_names = [' '.join([fn.split(' ')[0],fn.split(' ')[1][0],fn.split(' ')[2][0]]) for fn in full_names]`

Answer (score 4):

Одна строчка, используя имена из вопроса:

```
short_names = map(shorten_to_initials, full_names)
```

где определение `shorten_to_initials()` можно в другое место в коде передвинуть без потери понимания:

```
def shorten_to_initials(full_name):
    """u'Иванов Иван Петрович' -> u'Иванов И.П.'"""
    last, name, patronymic =  full_name.split()
    return u"{last} {name[0]}.{patronymic[0]}.".format(**vars())
```

Это может сломаться, например, для букв, состоящих из нескольких символов. See [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Не стоит злоупотреблять сокращениями типа: `"{} {[0]}.{[0]}.".format(*full_name.split())` в Питоне.